# Magical libc.math.abs in Cython

Tags: python, math, cython

How does cython manage to `cimport abs` from `libc.math`

```
from libc.math cimport abs
```

if it is not there?

```
> grep abs Cython/Includes/libc/math.pxd
<nothing>
```

I even tried deleting everything from that file (I got a 0 length `math.pxd`)
yet it somehow contrives to find `abs` there.

**Update**

This is my third question about cython:

In the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038496/cython-error-adding-complexdouble-to-double) I found out that `libcpp.complex` is not written quite correctly, @axil raised a ticket in cython github repo then made a pull request with my fix that replaces about 20% of complex.pyd lines. So it makes sense for cython user to look into includes directory from time to time.

The [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067131/absdouble-complex-in-cython) addressed the `abs` builtin which supposedly was overlooked by cython authors in that it doesn't translate python code to c at all and calls the original python abs function. The solution involves patching `cython/compiler/Builtin.py` file.

Now my third question is again about `abs` function, now imported from 'libc.math'. It does work, but they way it works looks really bizzare to me. In my opinion there's quite enough magic in Cython without importing a function from a module that doesn't have it.

**Update 2:**

It turns out that is that `abs()` does not get imported from `lib.math`. In fact, this import is just ignored:

```
 1: from libc.math cimport abs                   # nothing changes when I comment it out
 2: 
+3: def f():                                     # yellow
+4:     cdef double complex aaa = 1 + 2j         # white 
+5:     cdef double bbb = abs(aaa)               # yellow
```

> __pyx_t_1 = __pyx_PyComplex_FromComplex(__pyx_v_aaa); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 5, __pyx_L1_error)
>       __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
>       __pyx_t_2 = PyNumber_Absolute(__pyx_t_1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 5, __pyx_L1_error)
>       __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
>       __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
>       __pyx_t_3 = __pyx_PyFloat_AsDouble(__pyx_t_2); if (unlikely((__pyx_t_3 == (double)-1) && PyErr_Occurred())) __PYX_ERR(0, 5, __pyx_L1_error)
>       __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_2 = 0;
>       __pyx_v_bbb = __pyx_t_3;

It should be noted though that @DavidW's patch from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067131/absdouble-complex-in-cython) fixes it in the sense that last line becomes white (gets compiled to c). Yet I don't understand why cimporting abs is ignored.

**Update 3**

Yet another observation is that importing `abs()` from `libcpp.complex` works as expected:

```
# distutils: language = c++
from libcpp.complex cimport complex, abs

ctypedef complex[double] dcomplex

def f():
    cdef dcomplex aaa = dcomplex(1, 2)
    cdef double bbb = abs[double](aaa)
    return bbb
```

So it isn't a big deal for cython to cimport a builtin.

Comment: I think it's due to the automatical optimization, http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/reference/language_basics.html#python-built-ins, built-in `abs`  is translated , even in the `cimport`, to `PyNumber_Absolute`, `fabs`, `fabsf`, whatever.

Comment: @oz1 Same thing happens when I write `from libc.math cimport abs as myabs` and `cdef double bbb = myabs(-10)`. Also when I inspect the c code for bbb initialization it is different if I use the mentioned import line or comment it out. It really uses `abs` from "math.h", not the builtin one.

Comment: Depending on the usage, `abs` will be translated to diffrent function call,`from libc.math cimport abs as myabs

cdef double a = myabs(3+4j)
cdef double b = myabs(-10)
cdef double c = myabs(-10.0)
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)`, just see the c code.  BTW, I didn't get your real problem, does `abs` cause some error or bug?

Comment: @oz1 Not sure what you're trying to say and how your comment applies to my question. After importing `abs` from `libc.math` it works correctly. And of course it is translated to a different function call depending on the argument type. Did I say the opposite somewhere? The question is how does cython import a function from a pxd module that doesn't have this function.

Comment: @oz1 Abs is the very first and the most simple function call I could think of, which is also needed in my work. My real problem is that cython, a tool for converting python code to c/c++ code doesn't  convert `abs()` to c/c++.

Comment: @oz1 There's yet another cython issue: in your code `cdef double a = myabs(3+4j)` cython should've generated a compile error because there's no notion of complex numbers in `"math.h"`. Instead it inserts a python call with all the accompaining conversions. It is worth creating yet another so question or github bug report. Moreover, even builtin `abs()` is unable to cope with `double complex` - that is what my [second cython question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067131/absdouble-complex-in-cython) is all about.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins I don't know the answer to this but a bit of testing shows that `cimport` behaves oddly with names that are the same as Python builtins. Try compiling `from libc.math cimport ord` for example. I don't know what that means or why.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins Sorry to misunderstood your question. I don't know too much about the compiler-level of cython. I always try to use cython in a 'safe' way. eg: I never use `from libc.math cimport abs`:) But it does make sense to make this clear. Hope someone will give a good explanation

Comment: @DavidW Yes, importing `ord` looks odd. It is missing from both `libc.math` and `"math.h"`, yet no error is generated and the builting odd keeps being used (like with `abs()`, the C version of it, so it's not really a big deal). I've also succeeded in importing double and even complex from literally empty `libc.math` without any warnings whatsoever :) Yet deleting that `math.pxd` file altogether breaks the compilation. As well as importing a non-builtin from empty file (like `sin()`).

Comment: @oz1 I hoped I won't have to go that deep either :) Thanks for you help anyway!

Comment: Related: Note that the current release version of Cython is missing a lot of declarations in `math.pxd` from `math.h`. This is fixed in Cython 3, as per [this commit](https://github.com/cython/cython/commit/4f9e2e37eb06de526938c428f35a355cdcc466f3#diff-408a441b237070a78e70a27b3bfe0462).

Answer (score 4):

In C, the "built-in" or globally-available absolute-value function `abs` is only for integers (and `labs` for longs). The absolute-value function or floating-point numbers is `fabs`, found in "math.h".

This translates to using `libc.stdlib.abs` for integers, `libc.math.fabs` for doubles, and `abs` (built-in) for all Python objects. Only the built-in `abs` requires GIL.

Answer (score 1):

Cython pxd files located in {Python_path}/.../site_packages/Cython/Includes
So if look at libc/stdlib.pxd then you will see that stdlib.pxd got abs() and libcpp/complex.pxd have a template function abs for complex numbers template class. In libc/math.pxd you can find fabs() for floating point types.